# Runtime java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/access/BeanFactoryReference after Spring upgrade from 4 to 5

Tags: java, spring, gradle, build

I upgraded my Java application from Spring 4 to Spring 5 and i am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/access/BeanFactoryReference error while running on tomcat server.
followed by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BeanFactoryReference

Please help me to fix this issue..

Below are dependencies in my build.gradle file

```
compile 'org.springframework:spring-context-support:5.2.11.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.2.11.RELEASE'
    
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:5.2.8.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.2.8.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:5.2.8.RELEASE'

compile 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-sftp:5.2.11.RELEASE'

compile 'org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:3.0.9.RELEASE'
    
compile 'com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.14'

compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.10'

compile 'wsdl4j:wsdl4j:1.6.3'
compile 'commons-discovery:commons-discovery:0.2'
compile 'javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:1.1'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:24.1.1-android'
compile('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.2') {
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
}
compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.1.3.Final'

compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
compile 'commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.4'

compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.13.3'

compile 'com.lmax:disruptor:3.3.4'

compile 'org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:4.4.1'

compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.2'

providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
providedCompile 'javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jstl-api:1.2'
providedCompile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
providedCompile 'org.glassfish.web:jstl-impl:1.2'
providedCompile 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:2.0'
providedCompile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.12'

testCompile 'org.springframework:spring-test:5.2.11.RELEASE'
    
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
testCompile 'foo-commonj:foo-commonj:1.1.0'
testCompile 'commonj-twm:commonj-twm:1.1.0'


integrationTestCompile sourceSets.main.output
integrationTestCompile configurations.testCompile
integrationTestCompile sourceSets.test.output
integrationTestRuntime configurations.testRuntime
```

Please let me know if more information required from my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by myself. I cleaned tomcat history by tomcat -> clean
I did gradle refresh, ran again on tomcat server and issue resolved.

Tomcat was taking application's old build. In previous build I had spring-ws-core:2.x.RELEASE which was bringing spring-beans.4.x.jar and it is incompatible with other spring 5 jars.
so root cause was incompatible jars and then tomcat cache build.

Comment: I had similar issue and it resolved by same steps. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to fix, you must go through the process of upgrading/migrating from Spring 4.x to 5.x. That is a major upgrade so it is expected that classes would be removed.

As stated by core Spring developer [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20630#issuecomment-453462268):

> I'm afraid `BeanFactoryReference` and co are simply gone in 5.0. You need to clean up your dependencies so that they are all Spring Framework 5.0 compatible (...)

With that said, you will need to read over the upgrade guide for 5.0 [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x#upgrading-to-version-50), then work you're way up all the way to 5.3

Comment: Thank you Francisco for your response. Yes, after all libraries making compatible, issue was resolved but tomcat was taking previous build and it seemed as not resolved.
Tomcat clean resolved the issue.